# Error: "type 'UnspecifiedInvalidResult' is not a subtype of type 'LibraryElementResult' in type cast" in Flutter Hive

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive, build-runner

I run `flutter packages pug run build_runner build`, the normal command with which you would create a TypeAdapter in Flutter, I get the following error:

> type 'UnspecifiedInvalidResult' is not a subtype of type 'LibraryElementResult' in type cast

It says that It founds the error In the following file:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part 'storedItem.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Person extends HiveObject {

  @HiveField(0)
  String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  int age;
  
  Person({required this.name, required this.age});
}
```

I mean that's the Code of the documentation! What did I wrong?

Btw:
Developing on a M1 MacBook Air, Flutter 2.2.3, Android Studio 4.2.2

Comment: idk why most of these deleting pubspec lock and flutter clean works

Answer (score 16):

I was finally able to fix this by deleting my pubspec.lock file and running flutter pub get again.

Comment: Same this worked for me. I didn't have any `HiveType`s in my new project yet but I had the same error

Comment: wonderful, worked

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix this by deleting my pubspec.lock file, run `flutter clean` and running `flutter pub get` again.

Comment: same for me just run these and it is all done.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem right now. Finally figured out what I was doing wrong.

The solution is the name of the dart file should be used in `part"file_name.g.dart";` and there should be no gaps in the file name. For example, my dart file name was `Data Entry.dart` and I was using `part"entries.g.dart";`. That's why it was showing this error. Then I changed the code to `part"Data Entry.g.dart";`. It was still showing the error.

Then finally I changed the file name to `entries.dart` and used `part"entries.g.dart";` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

`source_gen: 1.0.3`  helped in my case

Answer (score 0):

Steps to fix the ploblem:

- execute `flutter clean`.
- deleted `pubspec.lock`.
- run `flutter pub get`.

**DONE**

Now run the `build_runner` and shuld work

Comment: you meant deleting `pubspec.lock` instead of `pubspec.yaml`